# Azure Cognitative Image Analisys cant handle alpha-channel on images?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

So I am using Azure Cognitative Services, more specifically the Image Analysis service trying to get the colors for an image.

My problem is that the majority of my image is transparent so if I encode it as a jpeg it simply thinks Black is the dominant color and as a png it says White, regardless of other colors.

Is this intended, or am I failing in encoding the image correctly?

```
 AzureVisionJson visionJson = null;
                    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        bodyColorBmp.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        visionJson = AzureCognitiveOcr.MakeColorRequest(_azureVisionSubcsriptionKey, memStream);
                   }
```

Anyone have any idea if it's possible to get the Image Analysis to actually ignore the transparent pixels?

Im talking about this service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-detecting-color-schemes

Comment: I am going to remove the azure-cognitive-search tag, because it is azure-cognitive-services related.

Comment: Why are you encoding it as a Jpeg? What is your initial file format? Do you have a sample file so that we can test?